# Remove double quotes from csv row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have two files: src.csv and dst.csv. The code below reads the second row from src.csv and appends it to dst.csv. The issue is the output in dst.csv is contained within double quotes ("").

Expected result:

```
10, 5, 5, 10, 1
```

Output:

```
"10, 5, 5, 10, 1"
```

I have tried using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' '` in csv.writer and it does remove the quotes though the output now contains a blank space after each csv value.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

with open('src.csv', 'r') as src, open('dst.csv', 'a', newline='') as dst:
    wr = csv.writer(dst, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
    next(src)
    for row in src:
        wr.writerow([row.rstrip('\n')])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use `wr.writerow(row)`.

Comment: Changing this gives:

`1,0, ,,5, ,,5, ,,1,0, ,,1, `

Comment: You must not have done what I meant. See @tdelaney's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39864180/355230).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't split the source file rows into columns so you just ended up writing a 1 column csv. Use a reader instead:

```
import csv

with open('src.csv', 'r') as src, open('dst.csv', 'a', newline='') as dst:
    wr = csv.writer(dst, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
    next(src)
    reader = csv.reader(src)
    for row in reader:
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `csv.reader()` to read row as list of number - now you read row as one string and csv.writer has to add `""` because you have `,` in this string.